# Permanently increase swap size?

Tags: linux, swap

I'm using these commands to increase swap size (on existing swap):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/.swapfile bs=1M count=1024
mkswap -v1 /.swapfile
swapon /.swapfile
```

It does increase, but after server reboot, it defaults back to previous swap size. How can I make it permanent, so it would stay at size I set?

**Update**
Running `swapon -s` reveals:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/mnt/512MiB.swap        file        524284  92      -1
```

OS is `Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)`

So I suppose it uses that default swap.

Comment: There must be a script running at boot time that generates the swap file.  What OS are you running?

Comment: @agtoever I supose using gparted, you need to load from cd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If available, the most efficient way is to increase the size of the swap partition (assumed that there is one; you can check using `swap -s`). [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/389067) is an instruction to do so.

In this particular case, the OS is virtualized, and there is no access to partitioning tools. In that case, a swap file (next to a "normal" swap space) is perfectly suited.

Make the swap file using as described in the original question (the name of the swap file and its location does not matter):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/.swapfile bs=1M count=1024
mkswap -v1 /.swapfile
swapon /.swapfile
```

It's imortant to set the permissions of the swap file to `600`, because you don't want normal users to see what's in memory (could be plain text passwords!), so: `chmod 600 /.swapfile`

Next, add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

`/.swapfile  none  swap  sw  0 0`

Comment: That just automatically starts swapping on that file. It does not change the size (though if you only automatically started swap on ONE file/partition and forgot to add the seconds then to sum of swap space would increase.)

Comment: What do you mean by does not change the size? Looking with `free -m` I can see that swap stays increased even after restart.

Comment: It does not increase or decrease the size of the swap partition or a swap file. It merely turns more on. Compare it to "I add a second taxi", "thus the car becomes bigger".

Comment: Still don't get it. So it means that additional swap is useless now? How then to add it so it would "change" the size?

Comment: Yeah I want that, I just didn't find solution where it would let you increase current swap size. For some reason it showed how to add second swap partition. I used this guide: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442430-increase-your-available-swap-space-with-a-swap-file

Comment: @agtoever but this needs to be done using boot disk and I'm using server which can't be shutdown like that and I can't even boot it like that as I don't have access (its in virtual environment, which I can't access directly)

Comment: I edited the answer to be more complete and concise. Mind the chmod, because it is a security risk. I suggest we delete our comments and you accept your own answer.